# loopback-testing: what is the correct way to test with a user and role

Tags: node.js, testing, loopbackjs

I am trying to write tests with loopback-testing.

I am a bit confused, and there's barely any documentation at all.

I'd like to test a model for which only a user with role "admin" has WRITE rights.

Now, if I do:

```
lt.describe.whenCalledByUserWithRole(test_config.adminUserCredentials, test_config.adminRole, ....)
```

`loopback` will actually create a user with `test_config.adminUserCredentials` prior to login!
Why is it doing that?

The correct behavior, IMHO, should be:

- Create the user in test setup
- Create the role in test setup
- Associate the role to the user
- When running the test, only check that the user has rights on the requested operation

But it looks to be quite tricky to do with loopback-testing. If I create a user in setup, the test will crash because `whenCalledByUserWithRole` will in the process try to create the user again, which loopback will deny saying the user already exists. If I don't create a user and call `whenCalledByUserWithRole`, this user won't be associated to the "admin" role for some reason (even if the name suggests so), and the test fails.

How do I do this correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up writing an own extension to loopback-testing:

```
var app         = require('../server/server.js');
var _beforeEach = require('loopback-testing').beforeEach;
var _describe = require('loopback-testing').describe;

var helpers = exports = module.exports = { 
  describe: _describe,
  it: _it,
  beforeEach: _beforeEach
};

_beforeEach.givenExistingUserWithRole = function(credentials, role, optionalHandler) {
  console.log("_beforeEach.givenExistingUserWithRole");

  before(function(cb) {
    var test = this;
    username = credentials.username;
    pwd      = credentials.password;

    loginCredentials = {username:username,password:pwd};
    app.models.User.login(loginCredentials, function(err, token) {
      if(err) {
        console.log("Error logging in test user! " + err);
      } else {
        console.log("Test user successfully logged in.");
        test.loggedInAccessToken = token;
        console.log(token);
      }   
       cb();
    }); 
  }); 

  afterEach(function(done) {
  var test = this;
  console.log(this.loggedInAccessToken);
  this.loggedInAccessToken.destroy(function(err) {
    if(err) return done(err);
    test.loggedInAccessToken = undefined;
    done();
    }); 
  }); 
}
```